# Why list comprehension with many interactions is much slower than multiple list comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, spyder

When I try to run a list comprehension with a large number of interactions, the command takes too long and does not output an answer. However, if I break it in small lists, I can get the job done.

Example:
This first one takes "infinitely":

```
cl = [bool(sum([x in c_groups.index[k] for x in bb_sorted.columns[5:11]])) for k in range(len(c_groups))]
```

While this works just fine in a reasonable time:

```
cl1 = [bool(sum([x in c_groups.index[k] for x in bb_sorted.columns[5:11]])) for k in range(1000)]
cl2 = [bool(sum([x in c_groups.index[k] for x in bb_sorted.columns[5:11]])) for k in range(1000,2000)]
cl3 = [bool(sum([x in c_groups.index[k] for x in bb_sorted.columns[5:11]])) for k in range(2000,3000)]
cl4 = [bool(sum([x in c_groups.index[k] for x in bb_sorted.columns[5:11]])) for k in range(3000,len(c_groups))]
cl = cl1 + cl2 + cl3 + cl4
```

I copied this example from something exactly as I wrote it, but I it happened also in other situations. I have no idea of what happens here, and it does not feel right to avoid problems breaking list comprehensions down like this.

Why does this happen, and how to avoid it (without breaking sentences like that)?

**EDIT:**

I tried the same script again, and I found out that the error happens only when using Spyder (running in shell works fine). Thus, it must be an issue with the IDE, I suppose (makes sense?).

Comment: No idea if that would help you with your problem, but you could probably use `any(...)` instead of `bool(sum([...]))`

Comment: How much free RAM does your machine have? I guess it could have something to do with memory allocation.

Comment: It shouldn't be faster to do it in smaller batches. What exactly is `c_groups`, `c_groups.index` and `bb_sorted`? This question lacks a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Actually, I tested it again and noticed now it must be an issue with the IDE (Spyder). Sorry I did not realize that before.

Comment: @go2nirvana : The RAM does not seem to be on its limit (according to indication on a tray app).

Comment: @HåkenLid : Sorry I could not post a reproducible code in here. I will improve my example and edit my question.